# Need a nested SQL query which takes the count from the first query and calculate a new count

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query which calculates the number of distinct fileIds in a table. Given below is the query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT `fileId` AS FileId, Count( FileId ) AS NumberOfTags
FROM `Tag`
GROUP BY `fileId`
ORDER BY NumberOfTags DESC
```

The output of this query is given below,

```
 FileId. NumberOfTags

 1  500

 2 500

 3 550

 4 550

 5 550
```

I need to get the count of number of Files coming under each NumberOfTag value. Sample output should be something similar to this

```
 NumberOfTags Number of Files

 500 2

 550 3
```

The results of the first query is pretty large, it has around 3 Million rows. I tried to create a table of the results of the first query but it also failed with an error

```
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

Can someone please tell me how to create a nested query to do this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I'm getting the question, but it sounds like you need a subquery:

```
SELECT NumberOfTags, COUNT( FileId ) as NumberOfFiles
FROM (
  SELECT `fileId` AS FileId, Count( FileId ) AS NumberOfTags
  FROM `Tag`
  GROUP BY `fileId`
  ) as rows
GROUP BY NumberOfTags
```

Answer (score 1):

Denis query is how you would correctly do it.

Just to explain why it works, when you want to nest a query you create a temporary table from the nested query output by surrounding it with parentheses and assigning it a name with "as."

Select <...>
From ( nested query ) as SomeTempTableName;